# CakePHP CMS Cascading Delete works in local, but not in production?

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, content-management-system

So I've managed to deploy my CakePHP to EB and when I've tried testing by handling the User table. I've managed to create/edit a user, but when I try deleting one I get "Table class for alias TABLENAME could not be found." The funny thing is when I do the same thing, even connected to the same DB, with the same configuration, running the same command (PHP -S) this works in local so I'm pretty bamboozled. The first thing that came to mind is that my nginx is configured wrong, but I can normally edit and delete entries in the TABLENAME table so I'm assuming all files related can be located ? Also I've added the belongsTo and hasMany to respective table class files.

I honestly don't even know what to try anymore. Also for some reason my DebugKit won't work in EB either (works locally) so it's making my life so much tougher. Has anyone had any similar issues ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have no experience with EB, so I can't help you there, but to get debug kit running in an environment that it can't identify as local itself (for security reasons it won't show up otherwise), you can configure `DebugKit.safeTld` to include the non-local-ish TLD where you app is running, or even use `DebugKit.forceEnable` to just make it always run, see **https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html#configuration**. And of course debug mode for your app needs to be enabled.

Comment: Hmm, when I do this, I get "Missing DB connection" when I open the app for some reason ? Is it because I removed the test connection and DebugKit needs it ?

Comment: Hmm, when I do this, I get "Connection to Sqlite could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file" even with the test connection in app being Postgres. I have no mentions of Sqlite in my code and my Driver is set to Postgres on both test and prod configs

Comment: "sqlite" keyword appears in only 3 places in my repo and those are all comments

Comment: [**DebugKit by default uses SQLite**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html#database-configuration) for data storage. Make sure that permissions allow access to `tmp/debug_kit.sqlite`.

Comment: The permissions are 777 and during runtime debug_kit.sqlite isn't created at all ?